# Soft shutdown of a cloud role so it ignores new action requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, azure

I was wondering if it's possible to do a 'soft shutdown' or 'soft reboot' of a cloud service. In other words the server would refuse new incoming http requests (which come in through ASP.net controller actions), but would finish all existing requests that are in progress. After this happens the server would then shutdown or stop as normal.

#### Server Version

Azure OS Family 3 Release
Windows Server 2012
.NET 4.5
iis-8.0
asp.net 4.0

#### Usage Scenario

I need to ensure that any actions responding to remote http requests currently in progress finish before a server begins the process of shutting down or becoming unresponsive because of a staging to production swap.

I've done some research, but don't know if this is possible.

A hacky work around might be using a CloudConfigurationManager variable to initiate that an error 503 code should be returned on any incoming actions over http, but then I'd have to sit around and wait for a while without any way to verify that condition.  At that point I could then stop the service or perform a swap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/01/14/the-right-way-to-handle-azure-onstop-events/ for information on how to drain HTTP requests when a role is stopping (attaching image below, I don't know why the source uses an image instead of text...):

[image: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/01/14/the-right-way-to-handle-azure-onstop-events/]

Also note that doing a VIP swap won't affect the role instances themselves or any TCP connections to the instances, so nothing should become unresponsive just because you do a VIP swap.  Once you begin shutting down the staging deployment after a VIP swap that is when the code above will help drain the requests before actually shutting down.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I need. I'll let you know how the results go.